# How to create component in runtime created panel?

Tags: delphi

I want to create panel components including several labels. My code is as follows, and the panel is created but labels don't. The error message is 'Access violation at address 0040452A... Read of address FFFFFFD0.'

```
rScan:=rScan+1;
// create panel
with TPanel.Create(self) do begin
  Parent:=sxScan;
  Name:='pnScanItem'+IntToStr(rScan);
  Left:=0;
  Top:=4+(rScan-1)*67;
  Width:=983;
  Height:=68;
  Caption:='';
  vHandle:=Handle;
end;
// create label
with TLabel.Create(self) do begin
  Parent:=TWinControl(vHandle);
  Name:='lbScanNam'+IntToStr(rScan);
  Left:=11;
  Top:=4;
  Font.Size:=14;
  Caption:='.....';
end;
```

Comment: As a broad rule, any cast is suspicious and should cause for though. I guess your though process when the compiler objected to the original type mismatch was to cast the handle to be a control. Don't think that way.

Comment: I strongly suspect that had you not used **with**: you would have declared a local variable to reference your new `TPanel` and would have had no trouble setting the `Parent` of your new `TLabel` _correctly_. And thus by happy accident could have avoided your mistake altogether. While yours is not a common **with**-induced mistake, the fact remains: certain kinds of mistakes are far too easy when using **with**. Given there's a clean, trivial alternative to **with**: the risks far outweigh the benefits. And you'd do well to not use **with** at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot typecast a `TPanel.Handle` as a `TWinControl`, because it isn't one. It's a window handle.

Save a local reference to the panel you're creating instead, and use it as the parent for the label.

```
var
  Pnl: TPanel;
begin
  Pnl := TPanel.Create(Self);
  with Pnl do
  begin
    Parent := ...
    // Other panel setup code
  end;
  with TLabel.Create(self) do
  begin
    Parent := Pnl;
    // Other label setup code
  end;
end;
```